# automating our RDC setup with a .bat file

Tags: powershell, batch-file, windows-scripting

I'm making a windows script to automate our remote desktop set up. The idea being that a user can just click on the file, input the required information and all, or as much of the admin part will be done.

So the first part of our procedure is to add the workstation to the security group `RDS_Enabled_Workstations`.

For this I made this code:

```
"RDS_Enabled_Workstations" | Add-ADGroupMember -Members `
    (Read-Host -Prompt "Enter PC Name")
```

the problem is that I'm adding a computer and for this whoever runs the script needs to add `$` at the end of the name Eg `workstation122$`.

I need it so that they can just put in the name of the workstation and move along without getting the error:

```
Add-ADGroupMember : Cannot find an object with identity: 'workstation122' under: 'DC=blue-zoo,DC=co,DC=uk'
```

because it thinks its a user.

I have tried placing the `$` outside the brackets but it still error.

Comment: If it's always the current workstation, then you could use %computername%$  ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work;

```
"RDS_Enabled_Workstations" | Add-ADGroupMember -Members `
    $(Get-ADComputer -Identity (Read-Host -Prompt "Enter PC Name"))
```

Comment: ah ok, so you defined the object identity. So is it set to users by default because that worked without putting in a identity?

Comment: No, or maybe I misunderstand what you are trying to say but - `Get-ADComputer` is looking for an object in ActiveDirectory where ObjectClass is `computer`. The `Identity` bit is the object's name. Assuming you're on a domain joined computer using a domain account - compare the following two lines;

`Get-ADUser $env:USERNAME | select Name, SamAccountName, ObjectClass`

`Get-ADComputer $env:COMPUTERNAME | select Name, SamAccountName, ObjectClass`

Comment: ah yes ok, I understand. thanks again, this will also help me later on.